# Run node file from ssh command through shell script

Tags: node.js, shell, ssh, nvm

Here I'm trying to run node file in AWS server with the ssh command through the shell script, where inside the shell file there is a command to run node file **(node test.js)**

Executing the below command, will run the shell file inside AWS server

```
ssh -i sample-test.pem ubuntu@ip 'bash -s' < my-folder/test.sh
```

- *test.sh* file [Shell file]

  ```
  node test.js
  ```
- *test.js* file [Node file]

  ```
  console.log("Venkatesh");
  ```

If I run the shell command directly inside the AWS server, node file runs perfectly. But if I run with the ssh command, it throws an error like this:

```
line 1: node: command not found
```

I have also tried from nodejs by using **node-ssh** package, same error occurs again.

How do I suppose to run a node file through shell script from ssh command?

Comment: did you install nodejs in? May I know what are the commands you used

Comment: Yeah! I have installed the nvm.
For your reference, these are the commands I have used :
sudo apt-get -y install build-essential libssl-dev
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.2/install.sh | bash
export NVM_DIR="${HOME}/.nvm"
[ -s "${NVM_DIR}/nvm.sh" ] && . "${NVM_DIR}/nvm.sh"
[ -s "${NVM_DIR}/bash_completion" ] && . "${NVM_DIR}/bash_completion"
nvm install 8
nvm use 8

Comment: Can you please type the command node -v, npm -v

Comment: v8.17.0 - node
6.13.4 - npm

Comment: Did you defined paths in bash profile?

Comment: output from this cmd may show useful info:  `ssh -i sample-test.pem ubuntu@ip which node`;  alt: `ssh ... type node`

Comment: Yes
echo 'export PATH=$PATH:/home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v8.17.0/bin/node' >> $HOME/.bashrc

Comment: Trim added path to the `node` containing directory

Comment: can you tell me in which file I have to add

Comment: What happen if you provide full path to node? run this command after you ssh into the server: `which node` and then take the full path and use it in `test.js`, `FULL/PATH/TO/NODE test.js`

Comment: Should use in test.sh right?
. /home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v8.17.0/bin/node test.js

Comment: yes, try that..

Comment: It's working...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [ROOT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/896358/root)

Add the node path while running the node file. The response of `which node` will be add to run the node file.

```
which node  #FULL/PATH/TO/NODE
FULL/PATH/TO/NODE test.js
```